# Unity - Bug in Unity Hub : Unity is already in list. You cannot locate the same version

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I launch a project via Unity Hub, the following message is printed : Unity is already in list. You cannot locate the same version.

[unity hub error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6z5T.png)

And when I want to access my project via Assets -> Scenes.

I get this : [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w98cU.png)

If I said "continue", my project is broken with a lot of errors to fix.

Have you a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you trying to open the project .. could you decripe every step?

Comment: Hi, my Unity Hub is broken with this error message :  "Unity is already on list. You cannot locate the same version."

So, I tried to access to my project via windows exploreur via Assets -> Scenes, but when I click on myScene.unity, I'm redirected on Unity Hub with the same error message : "Unity is already on list. You cannot locate the same version."

Comment: Before, when I wanna access to my project via windows exploreur, error message said that "Unity Editor uses 2019.4.5f version and my project
version was 2020.3.3f" so It may be create conflicts, so I delete my 2019.4.5f version, and I'm redirecting on Unity Hub with error message.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your screenshot, you are trying to open a project with an older unity version than the project's version. As it is written in the message, the operation is not supported and you should open it with at least the same version, or an older one. Make sure you have such a version installed in Unity Hub and to open the scene with this version.

You can still try to get everything to work by reimporting all you assets in Assets -> Reimport All but this will probably fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have the 2020.3.3f1 installed on my pc. So, how I can change the version of the launched editor ? My Unity Hub is broken. Message Error : Unity is already in list. You cannot locate the same version.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall unity hub completely (uninstall then install again) it may solve the problem. You may also try to reinstall unity. Also, check if your Unity license is up to date. You can also try to open the project through your system explorer and go to your project folder -> Assets -> Scenes -> the scene to open and open it this way, it is supposed to open the most adapted unity installation on your computer.

You can find maybe something to solve it if nothing of this works :
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-is-already-in-list-you-cannot-locate-the-same-version.785405/

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried and It doesn't work, if I open with assets->scenes, I got the same error message "unity is already in list". Yes, I'm gonna check this forum.